# (Should be easy) Selenium chromedriver (java) no element found error

Tags: java, selenium

I tried this exact code on other websites and it seems to work fine. It's just on pizza hut that it can't even locate an element let alone click on it. Thread.sleep() doesn't make a difference. The problem is between the commented *, according to the compiler. Here's the code.

```
package training;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class PizzaHut {

WebDriver driver;
@Test
public void open() throws Exception {
        //SET UP WEBDRIVER AND OPEN WEBSITE
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/1mr4n/Downloads/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.pizzahut.com/#/home");
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        //CLICK PIZZA
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        test("before");
        //**************PROBLEM*CODE**********************
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='lg-nav-pizza']")).click();
        //************************************************
        test("clicked pizza");

        //CLOSE BROWSER
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        driver.close();
    }

    public static void test(String x) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the code below and it worked just fine. No need for sleep or waits and I'm using Chrome also.

```
driver.get("https://www.pizzahut.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("lg-nav-pizza")).click();
```

Comment: Works for me, too.  User, what version is your Chrome?  And, what do you mean that the "compiler" reported a problem on that line?  What was the message?

Comment: Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)


org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='btn btn-link ph-titlecase ph-theme-active-link ng-binding ng-scope ng-click-active']"}

Comment: That selector is not in my code. Use my code and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one ,definitely it help you.**

package training;

```
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    
    public class PizzaHut {
WebDriver driver;
@Test
public void open() throws Exception {
        //SET UP WEBDRIVER AND OPEN WEBSITE
      //  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/1mr4n/Downloads/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.pizzahut.com/#/home");
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        //CLICK PIZZA
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        test("before");

        List<WebElement> webElements=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.btn-group.btn-group-lg.btn-group-justified.ph-header-navigation"))
        .findElements(By.cssSelector("div.btn.btn-link.ph-ghost-padding.ng-scope"));

for (WebElement element : webElements) {
if (element.getAttribute("title").equals("PIZZA")) {
element.click();
}
}

Thread.sleep(5000);

        test("clicked pizza");

        //CLOSE BROWSER
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        driver.close();
    }

    public static void test(String x) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not able to click it because it is an AngularJS tag, hence it takes some time to load: add some wait like below and it works (Here i'm just adding thread.sleep for the sake of simplicity,I've increased it to 15000ms):

```
    //CLICK PIZZA
    Thread.sleep(15000);
    test("before");
    //**************PROBLEM*CODE**********************
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='lg-nav-pizza']")).click();
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep()` is a bad practice and should be avoided. Use `WebDriverWait` instead.

Comment: Yeah, like I didn't know.